# iPhone - viewController calling viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 viewControllers A, B and C.

I am on vcA and I push vcB using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:YES];
```

While vcB is visible, I push vcC.

Now I am inside vcC and  would like to remove (or pop) both vcC and vcB at the same time and go directly to vcA. I don't want to go to vcB. How do I do that?

Is it possible to remove vcB from the stack silently while vcC is being shown?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can mess with them as an array

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: navigationController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo: removedViewController];
navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

Comment: Yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That's it! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Do we know if this respects the life management cycle? As in, will the removed views get all of their unload callbacks tiggered?

Comment: Since you are still referencing the actual values and merely creating a Mutable array and removing a single value then everything should still work. However removing it from that array may leave a retain on it. I would verify that everything is functioning correctly by attaching to instruments and performing the function over and over. And if you have memory leaks on that action then I would release the item removed from the array this way. Other then that it should function normally.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `A` is always the first controller that you push, then you should be able to do:

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Or if there may be other controllers on the stack before `A`, you can do:

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerA animated:YES]`

[References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController).

Comment: How nifty, somehow never noticed that method.

Comment: How would you take care of the case when the user presses the back button? There is no easy way to set a hook there.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on your `UINavigationController`...

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

If A is the root, popToRootViewController.

If not,assuming you are keeping to Apple's restrictions on undocumented API usage, I'd suggest that no, you cannot pop both C ans B from the list from C.

Any direct manipulation of the view stack would be hackish, and lead to lots of potential problem

Your best bet would be to set a global flag from C, pop it, and in B's viewWillAppear (WILL appear, non DID appear), you check for the state of said flag, and if set, immediately pop to A.

View B will not appear, and at worst will cause a small, probably imperceptible lag between C and A.

Comment: thanks. Apparently you can hack the stack officially, using Jason response. Thanks anyway.